# Why is this object being prematurely deallocated under ARC?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, automatic-ref-counting

I am having a problem setting the target for a UIButton:

```
//  TestViewController.m
@implementation TestViewController

@synthesize scrollContentView

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 SecondViewController *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];

[self.scrollContentView addSubview:secondViewController.view];
}

@end

// SecondViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1Click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 45, 280, 40);
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
}

- (IBAction)button1Click:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

The issue is when I click on the button I get the following error message:

> [SecondViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message
>   sent to deallocated instance 0x685c050
>
> (lldb)

I am assuming that the issue is I am passing just a view into the UIScrollView and I cannot access the controller.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message "`message sent to deallocated instance`" means that your `secondViewController` variable was not retained when the variable went out of scope at the end of `viewDidLoad`
however it's view, which contains it's button, was. Leading to a live object with a pointer to a dead object. Thus your crash.

Since you're using ARC, the quickest (possibly hackie) way would be to make the `SecondViewController` in ivar of `TestViewController`.

```
@implementation TestViewController{
    SecondViewController *secondViewController; // with ARC ivars are strong by default
}
```

And then change the line in `viewDidLoad` to:

```
secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
```

But I believe that the correct way (of course I don't know the specifics of your app) would probably be to use:

```
- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
```

A word of caution if this is an iPhone/iPod touch app; Apple has said for these devices the ratio should generally be one view controller to one screen of content. Again I don't know the specifics of your app, just wanted to mention it.

Comment: Thanks NJones. The first solution didn't work but the second was spot on.